# How can I read a text file that contains lists and add those lists to a list?

Tags: python, list, text-files

I'm working in a program that saves some products and arranges it to a text file according to their price.
the text file generated looks like this

```
['Kingstom', 0.92, 'china']
['sony', 16.88, 'USA']
```

But I need to incorporate a 'load' option, in which the user uploads the text file to add more products and generate another text file with the data arranged.

I've used

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt', 'r')]
```

but it returned me this

```
["['Kingstom', 0.92, 'china']", "['sony', 16.88, 'USA']"]
```

But I need a list like this to manage the data in a better way

```
[['Kingstom', 0,92, 'china'], ['Sony', 16.88, 'USA']]
```

So data[0] would be ['Kingstom', 0,92, 'china'] and so on.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is your best bet.

Comment: I would not save it in the file, using the square brackets, but just the values, separated by commas, like in csv. can you change the format of the file?

Comment: if possible you should use `json` format instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this sounds like a job for `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
[ast.literal_eval(x) for x in open("test.txt")]
```

however a better solution would probably be to save the data in a more common format (ie csv,json,xml,etc) and use the applicable decoder